# I need help importing wallet contract into mist after my old laptop got wet and had to get new one

Tags: mist, wallets, import, recovery

Could someone please help me as I am lost here.  I am holding some ether in mist.  I have the ether in a wallet contract for storage as I read this is more secure than a normal wallet.  I came home from work one day last week and I had left my laptop on my coffee table.  My 3 year old decided he wanted to wash the table and my laptop got wet.  It wont turn on now.  I have my keystore backed up on usb.  We decided to get a new laptop as my wife required one for work related stuff.  I installed the latest mist on the new laptop and synced the chain.  I went into mist, account, backup, and dragged my account keystore from usb into mist.  The problem is that the wallet showed up but the wallet contract associated with that wallet did not.  When I created the wallet contract and backed up my keystore originally I noticed that there was not a keystore file associated with the wallet contract itself.  I had inquired if this was ok and was told that the wallet contract associated with the wallet account would be saved along with the wallet in the same keystore file.  Is this not correct?  Did I do something wrong here?  It is a significant amount of ether and would like to explore any options I have to reclaim it. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: First, keep the old hard-disk.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have the old laptop.  I was going to see about getting in fixed if possible but not right away.  If the motherboard is cooked and it is fixed I should be able to access the ether again right? How does it work no that i imported the keystore files on the new laptop and the wllet contract was not there?  Will it be there still on the old laptop when the chain syncs?

Comment: I want to mention that I do have a complete mist file from the original mist browser

Comment: After digging around abit I was able to figure out how to import the contract wallet after all.  Thanks to anyone who took the time to read this post

Comment: It is worthwhile for you to put your solution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: The answer is probably: all you need is the public key of the contract. Did you find it somewhere?

Comment: Yes, correct.  I had sent ether to the DAO from the wallet contract and was able to use etherscan to find the corresponding address for the wallet contract.